# Using Rust Cargo TOML variables within VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

I need to prepare a number of exercises for students learning Rust. I've found the use of `${workspaceFolderBasename}` within the `program` field of my `launch.json` to be quite useful, as in:

```
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/target/debug/${workspaceFolderBasename}.exe"
```

This allows me to execute the program using `CTRL+F5`. However, this only works while the resulting executable has the same name as the workspace folder (i.e. `${workspaceFolderBasename}`). I note that the `name` field in my project's `Cargo.toml` file has a `name` field under `[package]` which controls the name of the resulting executable. Is there a way to use this field within `launch.json`?

Answer (score 3):

I want to propose a different approach. What if you define `cargo run` as a task in your `tasks.json` with a shortcut and let cargo handle the naming. That also has the advantage that, if students make a change ,cargo will compile it automatically when running `cargo run`.

This is how to do it:

- Create a `.vscode` folder on project directory.
- Create a `tasks.json` file in it.
- In the `tasks.json` file, my content is like this:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "run",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cargo run",
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

- Now when you run the command  `tasks: run task` on the command palette, you will see a new task called `run`. Clicking it will run `cargo run` on the workspace folder.

The documentation can be found in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks .

Sidenote: I checked the [VsCode Rust Plugin](https://github.com/editor-rs/vscode-rust) and it seems that they already have that functionality, so just let your students install that extension and they can run all the cargo tasks without doing the above steps.

Comment: Can you explain how to do that?

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out by hand. As for the plugin, I was led to believe "Rust (rls)" was the leading Rust plugin. I'm wary of installing multiple plugins dealing with the same language and toolset.

Comment: It took me a while to get to trying this. I'll put aside the point about using the plugin you mention for the moment. The main issue then is that `launch.json` is still needed to launch the `cppvsdbg` debugger. Again I am drawn to the `"program"` parameter of `launch.json`'s `configurations` array I mentioned, which needs the executable's filepath.

Comment: It may solve the launch problem, but still: is there a way to obtain a name from toml file?
For example, I still need executable path/name for Debug configuration.